# How to implement GNUMP in this Bernoulli numbers algortihm I wrote in C?

Tags: c, math, floating-point, gnu, bignum

I wrote this C algortihm to calculate Bernoulli numbers when the input is Nth, but it only works until 136th because of the floating-point limitations of C. I'm not a programmer, more a mathematician, A friend of mine tell about to implement this GNUMP, but I have no idea what is it, and how to do it. My algorithm is small and quick. Someone here can help me? Sorry for erros, english isn't my first language

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double over(int n, int k) {
    double result = 1.;

    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) 
        result *= (double) (n - i + 1) / (double) i;

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int m;
    double b = 0;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <index>\n", *argv);
        return -1;
    }

    m = atoi(*++argv);
    if (m % 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Index must be even!\n");
        return -2;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k <= m; k++) {
        double sign = 1.;
        for (int v = 0; v <= k; v++) {
            b += sign * over(k, v) * pow((double) v, (double) m) / ((double) (k + 1));
            sign = -sign;
        }
    }

    printf("B_%d = %f\n", m, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your friend undoubtedly was referring to [gmp](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: Something about big numbers...

Comment: I needed something like it years ago, I still needing.

Comment: There is plenty of excellent documentation at that site.

Comment: There is C code using GNU MP at https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bernoulli_numbers#C.

Comment: It lists the numbers, I need the algorithm that shows me the nTh on input like I did.

Comment: I believe the floating point limitations you are experiencing have nothing to do with C and everything to do with your floating point processor.  What you need is arbitrary precision, which can be found in multiple C libraries, including [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: Just use the same algorithm but with gmp types and functions instead of doubles and normal operators? Should be a straightforward conversion.

Comment: The code linked to by @lhf does calculate the n-th number. All you need to do is to replace their main-loop by your `atoi` code.

Comment: Sorry guys, I don't know how to do it, I just wrote he algorithm based on series, I'm a mathematician.

Comment: The 136th Bernoulli number is -84290226343367405131287578060366193649336612397547435767189206912230442242628212786558235455817749737691517685781164837036649737/4110. How far do you want your program to go (what is the largest input it needs to support), and how accurate do you need it to be? Why is not an existing table of Bernoulli numbers sufficient?

Comment: FYI, your program fails long before 136. 138 is just where overflow occurs, causing infinities and then NaNs. There are catastrophic rounding errors much earlier. For example, for 12 and 14, it prints -0.252197 and 1.125000, but the [expected results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) are -0.253113 and 1.166666. The formula looks correct, so I suspect the program suffers from precision issues even with these small inputs. For 14, the calculations involve 14^14, approximately 10^16, so you are pushing the limits of the IEEE-754 binary64 resolution.

Comment: @EricPostpischil 10000. It must calculate until 10 thousand!

Comment: Estimate how many operations the formula requires for the 10,000th Bernoulli number. Then estImate how much CPU time that might take with multiprecision arithmetic like GnuMP. Figure at least dozens of CPU cycles per elementary operation, perhaps hundreds for `pow`. Is that time okay for you? If not, how can you make the code faster? Do you have to calculate `over` from scratch each time? What about `pow`? Are there other ways to calculate Bernoulli numbers that are more efficient?